# getting total number to specific patients in rdlc report

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have made an rdlc report of total number of patients in a day and it works fine. I have the total number of female male patients, but when the report binds it returns a total equal to the number of rows in my data.
For example if I have 20 rows in my report then below when I print the count it returns the count in 20 rows.

How can I get it to be in only 1 row?

This is the query I'm using:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO 

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test_test_test]-- '2013/08/02' 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
(@date VARCHAR(20)) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SET NOCOUNT ON; 
      SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; 

      SELECT ( CASE 
                 WHEN OLD_NEW_PATIENT.OLD_NEW = 'new' THEN 
                 PATIENT_REF_MASTER.PAT_ID 
                 ELSE NULL 
               END )                                                 AS 'new', 
             ( CASE 
                 WHEN OLD_NEW_PATIENT.OLD_NEW = 'old' THEN 
                 PATIENT_REF_MASTER.PAT_ID 
                 ELSE NULL 
               END )                                                 AS 'old', 
             ---------------------------------------- 
             ( CASE 
                 WHEN GENDER_MASTER.NAME1 = 'Female' THEN GENDER_MASTER.NAME1 
                 ELSE NULL 
               END )                                                 AS 
             'Females', 
             ( CASE 
                 WHEN GENDER_MASTER.NAME1 = 'Male' THEN GENDER_MASTER.NAME1 
                 ELSE NULL 
               END )                                                 AS 'Males', 
             ------------------------------------- 
             CONVERT(VARCHAR, PATIENT_REF_MASTER.CREATION_DATE, 105) AS 
             'creation_Date', 
             PATIENT_REF_MASTER.SR_NO                                AS 'sr_No', 
             PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_FNAME + ' ' 
             + PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_SNAME                              AS 'NAME', 
             DEPT_ID                                                 AS 
             'Dept_ID', 
             DEPT_MASTER.DEPT_NAME                                   AS 
             'Dept_Name', 
             DOC_MASTER.DOC_ID                                       AS 
             'Doc_Master', 
             DOC_MASTER.DOC_FNAME + ' ' 
             + DOC_MASTER.DOC_SNAME                                  AS 
             'Doc_Name' 
             , 
             PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_ADDR 
             AS 'addr', 
             GENDER_MASTER.NAME1                                     AS 
             'Pat_Sex', 
             PATIENT_MASTER.AGE                                      AS 'age', 
             (SELECT Count(PATIENT_REF_MASTER.SR_NO) 
              FROM   PATIENT_REF_MASTER 
              WHERE  PATIENT_REF_MASTER.CREATION_DATE = @date)       AS 'count', 
             (SELECT Count(PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_SEX) 
              FROM   PATIENT_MASTER 
                     LEFT JOIN PATIENT_REF_MASTER 
                            ON PATIENT_REF_MASTER.PAT_ID = 
                               PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_CODE 
              WHERE  PATIENT_REF_MASTER.CREATION_DATE = @date 
                     AND PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_SEX = 2)                 AS 
             'F_count', 
             (SELECT Count(PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_SEX) 
              FROM   PATIENT_MASTER 
                     LEFT JOIN PATIENT_REF_MASTER 
                            ON PATIENT_REF_MASTER.PAT_ID = 
                               PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_CODE 
              WHERE  PATIENT_REF_MASTER.CREATION_DATE = @date 
                     AND PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_SEX = 1)                 AS 
             'M_count' 
      FROM   PATIENT_REF_MASTER 
             LEFT JOIN DBO.OLD_NEW_PATIENT 
                    ON DBO.OLD_NEW_PATIENT.CODE = PATIENT_REF_MASTER.OLD_NEW 
             LEFT JOIN DBO.DEPT_MASTER 
                    ON DEPT_MASTER.DEPT_CODE = PATIENT_REF_MASTER.DEPT_ID 
             LEFT JOIN PATIENT_MASTER 
                    ON PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_CODE = PATIENT_REF_MASTER.PAT_ID 
             LEFT JOIN DOC_MASTER 
                    ON DOC_MASTER.DOC_ID = PATIENT_REF_MASTER.DOC_ID 
             LEFT JOIN GENDER_MASTER 
                    ON GENDER_MASTER.CODE = PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_SEX 
      WHERE  PATIENT_REF_MASTER.CREATION_DATE = @date 
      --MONTH(Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date)=@month and Dept_ID=@dept 
      ORDER  BY PATIENT_REF_MASTER.SR_NO ASC 
  --  select Dept_Master.Dept_Name as 'Dept_Name', 
  --  count(Pat_ID) as 'Pat_ID' 
  -- 
  -- from Patient_Ref_master 
  --left join dbo.Dept_Master  on   Dept_Master.Dept_code  =   Patient_Ref_master.Dept_ID 
  --where MONTH(Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date)=@month and Dept_ID=@dept 
  --group by Dept_Master.Dept_Name 
  END
```

Comment: Can you include the query you're using now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to do to many things at once ;-)

The heart of your problem lies here:

```
SELECT Count(PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_SEX) 
              FROM   PATIENT_MASTER 
                     LEFT JOIN PATIENT_REF_MASTER 
                            ON PATIENT_REF_MASTER.PAT_ID = 
                               PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_CODE 
              WHERE  PATIENT_REF_MASTER.CREATION_DATE = @date 
                     AND PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_SEX = 1
```

By using this query within your query, it will return the total in each and every row. This is also why you can get away with writing the query and not using the `GROUP BY` clause.
I suggest you do all the work in this query with the exception of the count, and then use another query outside of this one for the count.

A secondary problem is that in your query you're requesting several details about each row, but you want it to come back in one row. You have to decide what you want ;).

In order to get just the counts in one row, try something like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO 

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test_test_test]-- '2013/08/02' 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
(@date VARCHAR(20)) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SET NOCOUNT ON; 
      SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; 

      SELECT Count(*) count, 
             Sum(CASE 
                   WHEN FEMALES IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                   ELSE 0 
                 END) F_Count, 
             Sum(CASE 
                   WHEN MALES IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                   ELSE 0 
                 END) M_Count 
      FROM   (SELECT ( CASE 
                         WHEN OLD_NEW_PATIENT.OLD_NEW = 'new' THEN 
                         PATIENT_REF_MASTER.PAT_ID 
                         ELSE NULL 
                       END )                                                 AS 
                     'new', 
                     ( CASE 
                         WHEN OLD_NEW_PATIENT.OLD_NEW = 'old' THEN 
                         PATIENT_REF_MASTER.PAT_ID 
                         ELSE NULL 
                       END )                                                 AS 
                     'old', 
                     ---------------------------------------- 
                     ( CASE 
                         WHEN GENDER_MASTER.NAME1 = 'Female' THEN 
                         GENDER_MASTER.NAME1 
                         ELSE NULL 
                       END )                                                 AS 
                     'Females', 
                     ( CASE 
                         WHEN GENDER_MASTER.NAME1 = 'Male' THEN 
                         GENDER_MASTER.NAME1 
                         ELSE NULL 
                       END )                                                 AS 
                     'Males', 
                     ------------------------------------- 
                     CONVERT(VARCHAR, PATIENT_REF_MASTER.CREATION_DATE, 105) AS 
                            'creation_Date', 
                     PATIENT_REF_MASTER.SR_NO                                AS 
                     'sr_No', 
                     PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_FNAME + ' ' 
                     + PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_SNAME                              AS 
                     'NAME' 
                     , 
                     DEPT_ID 
                     AS 'Dept_ID', 
                     DEPT_MASTER.DEPT_NAME                                   AS 
                     'Dept_Name', 
                     DOC_MASTER.DOC_ID                                       AS 
                     'Doc_Master', 
                     DOC_MASTER.DOC_FNAME + ' ' 
                     + DOC_MASTER.DOC_SNAME                                  AS 
                     'Doc_Name', 
                     PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_ADDR                                 AS 
                     'addr' 
                     , 
                     GENDER_MASTER.NAME1 
                     AS 'Pat_Sex', 
                     PATIENT_MASTER.AGE                                      AS 
                     'age' 
              FROM   PATIENT_REF_MASTER 
                     LEFT JOIN DBO.OLD_NEW_PATIENT 
                            ON DBO.OLD_NEW_PATIENT.CODE = 
                               PATIENT_REF_MASTER.OLD_NEW 
                     LEFT JOIN DBO.DEPT_MASTER 
                            ON DEPT_MASTER.DEPT_CODE = 
                               PATIENT_REF_MASTER.DEPT_ID 
                     LEFT JOIN PATIENT_MASTER 
                            ON PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_CODE = 
                               PATIENT_REF_MASTER.PAT_ID 
                     LEFT JOIN DOC_MASTER 
                            ON DOC_MASTER.DOC_ID = PATIENT_REF_MASTER.DOC_ID 
                     LEFT JOIN GENDER_MASTER 
                            ON GENDER_MASTER.CODE = PATIENT_MASTER.PAT_SEX 
              WHERE  PATIENT_REF_MASTER.CREATION_DATE = @date 
             --MONTH(Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date)=@month and Dept_ID=@dept 
             )T 
      ORDER  BY PATIENT_REF_MASTER.SR_NO ASC 
  END
```

I hope this helps, let me know if you need any more info.

**Edit**

Found a small mistake in the query I posted, the field names should have been `FEMALES` not `FEMALE` and `MALES` not `MALE`.

I also set up a scaled down example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64b95/2). Take a look and tell me what you think.

Comment: Giving error at SELECT Count(*) count, 
             Sum(CASE 
                   WHEN FEMALE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                   ELSE 0 
                 END) F_Count, 
             Sum(CASE 
                   WHEN MALE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                   ELSE 0 
                 END) M_Count

Comment: still giving an error "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test_test_test, Line 73
The multi-part identifier "PATIENT_REF_MASTER.SR_NO" could not be bound."

Comment: You need to debug your SP, I can't help you with that. Try using the info I gave you to decide what you want to do: get all the info or aggregate the totals in one line.