# How to get total in rdlc report

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, rdlc

I am binding a report of total patients for a day which are having female and male patients.

I am able to get number of male and female patients separately from my stored procedure.

When my report binds, I get 20 rows.

My report is working fine, except I am getting the count of both male and female patients 20 times (rows of my report).

I want to only show it once.

Do I have to write an expression for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting total number to specific patients in rdlc report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039681/getting-total-number-to-specific-patients-in-rdlc-report)

Comment: What is your query resultset like? If you are aggregating sums in your SP, there is no need to perform aggregation inside a report itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/229868/Grouping-in-rdlc-reports-using-microsoft-report-vi

[Rdlc Report Grouping without repeating data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569109/rdlc-report-grouping-without-repeating-data)