# rdlc group item position

Tags: asp.net, report, rdlc

I need a RDLC with fields in the following order:

code, account, due date and amount.
but how I need to group for due date to get day total, I only got this:

due date, code, account, amount.

Works fine, but, How could I get the requested order?

using asp.net, C# and vs2010

Comment: why cant you adjust it in the designer?

Comment: View this page and get idea how to group

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040306/how-to-get-total-in-rdlc-report/18044713#18044713

Answer (score 0):

as an workaround I hid the column group and repeat the same field, now as a single field, not grouped in the position that I wanted.